# Private Github repositories in dockerized rails application during build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, docker, ssh, docker-compose

I dockerized a new Rails 5 app with docker-compose.yml and I'm forwarding my ssh-agent socket into the container within the compose file.

If I build and run via docker-compose this is working fine, I can access the ssh key.

However, if I add bundle install to the build process, which fetches from private Git repositories and needs the SSH key, it's of course not yet available.

How can I solve this?

My current Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files are:
https://gist.github.com/solars/d9ffbc4c570e9a128d6b0254268d785a

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need ~/.ssh/id_rsa to clone `private repo` into docker image.

- One way: Copy your `id_rsa` and paste into docker image (`~/.ssh/` location)
- Other: you can create another temporary `id_rsa` (maybe run in a docker container and copy the .ssh file in your local machine). Copy the `new .ssh` folder into docker image (`~/ location`) alwasy when creating a docker image using Dockerfile. Next, Add you `new .ssh/id_rsa.pub` in your `github account -> settings -> SSH and GPG keys -> new SSH key`.

  **Working procedure:**  when you creating a new image, you are doing copy same `.ssh` folder inside image by Dockerfile, so `id_rsa` remaining same and the `id_rsa.pub` is added in your `github account` before. So, you are able to clone your `private repo` from your docker container always.

Comment: I only need it during build. I don't want to leave the key in the final docker image (e.g. if I would deploy it)

Comment: "need it during build" if you need only when you are creating docker image then you can `add it first` (Dockerfile) then `clone repo` and finally `delete .ssh` folder (Dockerfile).

Comment: @Christoph [known_hosts](https://gist.github.com/solars/d9ffbc4c570e9a128d6b0254268d785a#file-dockerfile-L26) file are needed to allow access when other machines accessing in the container.

Comment: aparently it's not that easy, the keys are still in the file unless you squash it: http://blog.cloud66.com/pulling-git-into-a-docker-image-without-leaving-ssh-keys-behind/